# how do we use request.session.setAttribute for already existing session variable to UI

Tags: ajax, list, jsp, session-variables

While loading the view page I am setting a session variable as:

```
request.session.setAttribute("list",list);
```

after that onclick of a button I am using ajax call to refresh the list. in backend I am able to see the latest list contents. But in UI I am using :

```
List<String> cList = (List<String>)session.getAttribute("list");
```

but even after the list is changed I am  not able see the latest list contents.Still the old list contents are displaying on the page. Need some suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

```
var refreshThisDiv= "refreshThisDiv";
            var goUrl= "unametest/getUserNamesList;
            var httpRequest=null;
            var refreshContent = "null";
            httpRequest = XMLHTTPObject();
            httpRequest.open("POST", goUrl, true);
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {ajaxFcuntion(refreshThisDiv,httpRequest); } ;
            httpRequest.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
            httpRequest.send(null);

//ajaxFcuntion
function ajaxFucntion(refreshThisDiv,httpRequest){

    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4)
    {
        if(httpRequest.status == 200)
        {
            results =  httpRequest.responseText; 
if(results!=null){

            <%

            List<String> list = (List<String>)request.getSession().getAttribute("list"); %>
//display data from list
}
```

}

Comment: Show more code, especially from the UI (the AJAX call, how the AJAX response is processed). These two lines are not enough to understand what's happening.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek hi Thanks for the reply. I have added the code. Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Actually as expected, you are mixing two different codes. You have to realize, *where* and *when* each code is executed - JSP on the server when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is send to the browser) and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response. For more details how to use AJAX, JSP and servlets together, read [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112686/how-to-use-servlets-and-ajax/) carefuly.

Comment: okay so how should I change the implementation to make it work . I have no idea and I am struck here. need some alternatives please. @Jozef Chocholacek

Comment: Read the linked answer, there is a lot of examples, one exactly doing what you need.